# Get query's row count in a Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, rowcount

I'm using `$this->db->get()->row_array()` in Codeigniter to get a single row of results from the database. I want to merge the results from all the different queries into a single array `$results`; I don't want to have to type in the column name to get the result of a single row.

**PHP Code**

```
// Query 1
$results = array();
$this->db->select('COUNT(listing_id) as num')
         ->from('listings')
         ->where('city', $city);
$result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
$results['num'] = $result['num'];
```

Is there something more succinct?

Maybe a two-liner?

```
$result = $this->db->get()->row_array();
$results['num'] = $result['num'];
```

Ideally, a one-liner would be great!

```
$results['num'] = first_element_of($this->db->get()->row_array());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know codeigniter and have never worked with it but this might work

```
// Query 1
$results = array();
$this->db->select('COUNT(listing_id) as num')
        ->from('listings')
        ->where('city', $city);

$results['num'] = $this->db->get()->row()->num;
```

The trick is that you can chain object member access. You cannot do this with arrays (`$foo->row_array()['num']`), so that's the problem here. If you were using good old mysql you should have a look at [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-result.php). There is no mysqli equivalent for this.

Depending on the return value of where() you can try and shorten it further to

```
$results = array('num' => 
    $this->db->select('COUNT(listing_id) as num')
        ->from('listings')
        ->where('city', $city)
        ->get()
        ->row()
        ->num
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has a dedicated helper method for counting rows in a result set.

`count_all_results()` will unconditionally return a non-negative integer.

All querying should be done in the model, so your model method can be:

```
public function countCityListings(int $city): int
{
    $this->db->where('city', $city)->count_all_results('listings');
}
```

Adding that return value to your controller's payload variable to be passed to the view can be:

```
$result['num'] = $this->your_model->countCityListings($city);
```